# one function returns result for multiple text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to javascript. I have written the code according to the textbox Id on change but I need to format the code to function call by have one function is it possible to return different values for different text box?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="1"  />
<input type="text" name="b" id="2"  />
<input type="text" name="result1" id="result1" />

<input type="text" name="c" id="3"  />
<input type="text" name="d" id="4"  />
<input type="text" name="result2"  id="result2"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#result1").change(function(){
        var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
        document.getElementById("result1").value = (a+b); 
    });
    $("#result2").change(function(){
        var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
        var d = document.getElementById("d").value;
        document.getElementById("result2").value = (c+d);
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're misunderstanding `name` and `id`. First of all, `id`'s cannot start with a number. Secondly, `getElementById` gets elements by ID (not name). Thirdly, if you want to use jQuery you should use `$('#a').val()` or `$('[name=a]')` instead of `document.getElementById('a').value`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo `id's cannot start with a number` It can in HTML5 compliant browser (and doctype) but it shouldn't because CSS3 still doesn't support it ;)  {CSS4 will}

Comment: You'd have better to rethink logic about your HTML markup, using some containers and classes, instead of IDs

Comment: You should bind events with `$("[name=a], [name=b]")` instead of `$("#result1")`

Comment: @A.Wolff Didn't know that - why would they update the HTML5 standard without releasing an early version of CSS4 (CSS3.5?) supporting it?! I can't think of a single website not using CSS.

Comment: @h2ooooooo you could use ID attribute in HTML or ID selector in javascript without caring about same selector in CSS if no specific style needs to be applied to this element. What HTML5 spec says it is that this is valide attribute. CSS said it is not valid selector using ID selector (even works using attribute selector e.g `[id="1"]`). CSS4 will handle both case.

Comment: @A.Wolff What about `document.getElementById`? Does it/has it ever cared?

Comment: @h2ooooooo http://jsfiddle.net/tja44/ It works on compliant browsers. CSS not working using ID selector: http://jsfiddle.net/tja44/1/  but works using attribute selector: http://jsfiddle.net/tja44/2/  Of course CSS attribute selector should never be used to target an ID, that's just a workaround. So finally; ID attribute starting with number shouldn't be used until CSS support it as ID selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use "starts with" JQuery selector like below.

Here it will fire for change event of all input text for `id` starts with `result`...i.e. for `result1`, `result2`... and so on.

and it will take values of two text boxes before it... and assign the sum to result box.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[id^='result']").change(function(){
  var value1 = $(this).before().val();
  var value2 = $(this).before().before().val();
    $(this).val(value1+value2);
});
});
```

But if you follow related ids or classes then you can do it very easily event though you are changing positions of the html elements.

consider below code with specific id assigned to them which are related to result tex boxes:

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="first_1"  />
<input type="text" name="b" id="second_1"  />
<input type="text" name="result1" id="result_1" class="result" />

<input type="text" name="c" id="first_2"  />
<input type="text" name="d" id="second_2"  />
<input type="text" name="result2"  id="result_2" class="result"/>
```

and related JQuery will be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[id^='result']").change(function(){
  var suffixValue = $(this).attr('id');
  suffixValue = suffixValue.split('_')[1];

  var value1 = $("#first_"+suffixValue).val();
  var value2 = $("#second_"+suffixValue).val();

  $(this).val(value1+value2);
});
});
```

please have a look at [JQuery Start with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: While it works, these solutions are fragile because of the dependence on the structure. If an element is moved - the whole thing breaks.

Comment: but this works for the given structure and no one can give generic solution if structure is not fixed. Then there should be some class pattern used to identify the html elements... this is not wrong answer. Let @ Navaneetha Krishnan decide if this is useful or not...

Comment: A downvote does not mean it is necessarily wrong. I think it is too fragile, others may disagree. The poster can decide whatever they want, regardless of my comment or downvote.

Comment: then every answer will be fragile if there should not be any specific html pattern (may be using structure, css etc)... and can you give me solution on this...

Comment: Yes, the solution is to use contextual IDs, or at least logical containers. Depending on the order of things (I guess I meant order before and not structure in general, sorry) is too fragile, in light of CSS issues like, for example, elements that have `float` should come before the rest of the elements on the same line.

Comment: and what if ids get changed or logical containers get changed?

Comment: IDs are must less likely to get changed, logical containers are less likely to get changed, but order is much more likely to get changed.

Comment: Everything does, but when code depends on factors that are much likely to change, it is fragile.

Comment: please see updated solution...it consist of solution for existing code structure and with ids

Comment: If you remove the first part (the dependence on the order), you would get my upvote.

Comment: Nope, it is still there. `.before().before()` and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="1"  />
<input type="text" name="b" id="2"  />
<input type="text" name="result1" id="result1" class="result" />

<input type="text" name="c" id="3"  />
<input type="text" name="d" id="4"  />
<input type="text" name="result2"  id="result2" class="result"/>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.result').blur(function(){
var result;
    if($(this).attr("id")=="result1")
    {
        result=parseInt($('#1').val())+parseInt($('#2').val());
       $(this).val(result);

    }
    else if($(this).attr("id")=="result2")
    {
        result=parseInt($('#3').val())+parseInt($('#4').val());
      $(this).val(result);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CjLWp/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are you listening change event of the result box. It should be binded to the value box.

If you want a single function to do it all, you can set a classname to all value box, then listen to it's change event.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TODO supply a title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".num-box").change(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('type1')) {
        var a = $("[name=a]").val();
        var b = $("[name=b]").val();
        $("[name=result1]").val(parseInt(a)+parseInt(b));
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('type2')) {
        var c = $("[name=c]").val();
        var d = $("[name=d]").val();
        $("[name=result2]").val(parseInt(c)+parseInt(d));
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="a" class="num-box type1" value=0 />
<input type="text" name="b" class="num-box type1" value=0 />
<input type="text" name="result1" />
<input type="text" name="c" class="num-box type2" value=0 />
<input type="text" name="d" class="num-box type2" value=0 />
<input type="text" name="result2" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the unified function should be -

```
$("#result1, #result2").change(function(){
var a = document.getElementById(this.id + "-a").value;
var b = document.getElementById(this.id + "-b").value;
this.value = (a + b); 
});
```

`this` is the context. In event listener functions, the context is the element that triggered the event, so when `result1` triggers the event, `this` will be the `result1` element.

Regarding `a` and `b` - you confused the `name` and `id` values here. If the IDs of those two elements are random, there is nothing stable you can do (if the order of the elements changes a bit, your code could fail) except using two different functions. My advise is to give them proper contextual IDs, so instead of `1` or `a`, it would be `result1-a` and `result2-a` and so on. Then you can prepend the ID of `this` and everything should work.

A general tip - IDs should start with letters and not numbers, because numbers will not match in CSS (3).

As for the `$("#result1, #result2")` part, like BhushanKawadkar suggested, it could be changed to `$("[id^=\"result\"")` and then you do not have to specify each and every ID.

Comment: But the two functions should output to different elements?

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: What about the fact that the first function add a + b, the second add c + d?

Comment: I did not notice, I will change the answer accordingly.

Comment: I need only one function for example calc()
{
it should invoke which two values to be added and display in the appropriate textbox
}

Comment: This is a single function. Care to elaborate more?

Comment: this is not the answer to question asked... it is same like asking to repeat code for every result text box ..

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Why not? If I understand correctly, the poster wanted a single generic function and this is what I provided.

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan - can you detail your need a bit more?

Comment: @PhistucK - I need only 1 function for example calculation ()
in tat function it should add 2 numbers
I have 10 textboxes
naming txtbox1,txtbox2,txtbox3,txtbox4,.
between every two text box i wil cal the fuction 
the format will be like
    <input type = text name="txtbox1">
    <input type = text name="txtbox2">
    <input type = text name="resultbox" onblur="calculation()">    
    <input type = text name="txtbox3">
    <input type = text name="txtbox4">
    <input type = text name="resultbox" onblur="calculation()">
the single function should return the value dynamically  for the result box

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan - unless you want to depend on order, which is too fragile in my opinion, you would have to change the names or IDs of the other elements so they would have certain relation to the name of changed element.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered jQuery? Then you can select elements by (for example) the same class.
So if I were you I'd do something like this

```
<textarea class="textbox">ABC</textarea>
<textarea class="textbox">DFC</textarea>
```

and then javascript:

```
$(document).on("change",".textbox",function()
               {
                  alert($(this).val()); 

               });
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/k4Y29/
Then after changing any contents - it will return its value.

ps. This can be used to any fields: input, select etc. jQuery means fun ;).

Comment: Your example is not really related to the question at hand.